# Can you use Awakened Spellbook to replace a 1st-level spell's damage type with force damage via Mage Armor, RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, damage-types

According to the *Player's Handbook* Ch. 9, "force" is a damage type, and "damage types have no rules of their own."

The Awakened Spellbook feature of the Order of Scribes Wizard states that under certain circumstances when casting a spell, "you can temporarily replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell in your spellbook".

The Mage Armor spell states, "You touch a willing creature who isn't wearing armor, and a protective magical **force** surrounds it until the spell ends. [...]" (emphasis mine).

It is well established that if the only spells in your spellbook were *Burning Hands* and *Magic Missile*, you could cause *Burning Hands* to deal force damage. But if the only spells in your Wizard's spellbook are *Burning Hands* and *Mage Armor*, could you still cause *Burning Hands* to deal force damage because "force" "appears in" *Mage Armor*?

**I'm asking from a purely R.A.W. (Rules As Written) perspective**—I'm fully aware that many DMs would rule against it, but I'd like to know whether doing so would be considered a house rule or an interpretation of the rules as written.

Comment: Related: [Does the Order of Scribes Feature Awakened Spellbook also change the damage type of Absorb Elements?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177958/does-the-order-of-scribes-feature-awakened-spellbook-also-change-the-damage-type?rq=1), [How does the Awakened Spellbook damage type replacement work, exactly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198635/how-does-the-awakened-spellbook-damage-type-replacement-work-exactly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This does not work as not all force is force damage

Force is a damage type, but mage armor does not deal force damage. The rules for damage types (*PHB*, p. 196) say:

> Different attacks, **damaging spells**, and other harmful effects deal different types of damage

*Mage armor* is not a damaging spell or harmful effect, so it deals no type of damage. That the word *force* appears in the spell does not mean it is force damage. For example, the word poison appears many times in the rules, in drow sleep poison, [*heroes feast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heroes-feast) grants immunity to poison, etc., but none of those mentions are poison damage.

As you only can "*replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell*", and *force* here is not a damage type, you cannot replace it.

Comment: Imagine what kind of nightmare would a feature like this be if it only required the specific *words* to appear in some other spell...

Comment: @Kryomaani "My Burning Hands deals 'willing' damage because Mage Armour works on *willing* targets."

Answer (score 4):

#### This does not work. *Mage armor* does not have a damage type.

Awakened Spellbook states:

> When you cast a wizard spell with a spell slot, you can temporarily replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell in your spellbook, which magically alters the spell’s formula for this casting only.

*Mage armor* does not have any damage type, so it fails to meet the requirement of Awakened Spellbook that you select a damage type that appears in another spell in your spellbook. Mentioning magical force is not the same thing as mentioning force damage.